# Flutter After loaded image show the widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have made a flutter program with local images but when I open the program it shows a white background for like 3 seconds then it shows the image. Is there any way to show a loading icon until the image is loaded properly. I have used the following code:

```
return Scaffold(
        body:Container(
          child: DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/bg/guest.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child:new Login_one_column(context),
          ),
        )

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CupertinoActivityIndicator as a loading icon